# Insert hyphens in variable with telephone numbers

Tags: string, stata

I have the following string variable containing raw telephone numbers:

```
* Example generated by -dataex-. To install: ssc install dataex
clear
input str9 telno
"453865397"
"518717023"
"697545175"
"514199417"
"582680471"
end
```

How can I insert a hyphen after every `3` digits?

Answer (score 0):

Here is another way to do it:

```
* Example generated by -dataex-. To install: ssc install dataex
clear
input str9 telno
"453865397"
"518717023"
"697545175"
"514199417"
"582680471"
end

generate wanted = substr(telno, 1, 3) + "-" + substr(telno, 4,3) + "-" + substr(telno, 7, 3)

list 

     +-------------------------+
     |     telno        wanted |
     |-------------------------|
  1. | 453865397   453-865-397 |
  2. | 518717023   518-717-023 |
  3. | 697545175   697-545-175 |
  4. | 514199417   514-199-417 |
  5. | 582680471   582-680-471 |
     +-------------------------+
```

It is hard to imagine a programmer using Stata easily without knowing basic functions. [This paper provides a starting point.](https://www.stata-journal.com/article.html?article=dm0058)

Comment: Yes this is simpler but I think I tried to eliminate the need for specifying the steps (`1,4,7`).

Comment: Thanks! But which method is the best?

Comment: Which is best for you is for you to decide. I upvoted @Pearly Spencer's answer and certainly have no objections to it.